# How can you use the enter key to transfer data from a textbox to a label

Tags: c#, textbox, label

I have a quick and simple question on a small project that I'm starting out on my own in C# for a Windows form program with Visual Studio 2010. I can't seem to find the correct code to transfer the input data that a user enters into a textbox with a method where they hit the enter key and it automatically enters a message in that label on the same form.

Such as in the following code (which has been edited as suggestions are provided):

```
    namespace MovieFinders2
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                //Named "Enter a Year"
            }

            private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

            }

            void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter || e.KeyCode == Keys.Return)
                {
                    label2.Text = textBox1.Text;
                    label2.Text = "Movies released before " + textBox1.Text;
                }
            } 

            private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

            }

            private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                label2.Text = textBox1.Text;
                label2.Text = "Movies released before " + textBox1.Text;
            }

            private void listBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

            }

            private void label3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                label3.Text = textBox1.Text;
                label3.Text = "Movies released in or after " + textBox1.Text;
            }
        }
    }

            private void label3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                label3.Text = textBox1.Text;
                label3.Text = "Movies released in or after " + textBox1.Text;
            }
        }
    }
```

I know that this program is in the early stages, but I"m trying to take this one step at a time and this is the road block that I have encoutered at this point; so any and all help would be greatly appreciated. Right now when I click the mouse on the lable it displays the message in that label. I need this to appear in the label when the user presses the enter key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter || e.KeyCode == Keys.Return) {
        label2.Text = textBox1.Text;
        label2.Text = "Movies released before " + textBox1.Text;
    }
}
```

TextBox.KeyDown event

Comment: I'm not sure where in the code that I have written for this portion that you are telling me about should be implemented. I have updated the code for where it is accepted, but I still have to use the mouse to click on the labels to display the message. The enter key does nothing which should transfer the data in the textbox to the label, – Rocky 25 mins ago

Comment: You have to assign this procedure as event hanler. Add "this.textBox1.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.textBox1_KeyDown);" to textbox1 section in your form1.Designer.cs file.
   "

Comment: If you need to Enter work for the entire form, not only textBox1, then you should add a handler for the entire form: this.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.textBox1_KeyDown);

Comment: Thanks for the input, I finally figured it out.